# How do we verify that Adobe Flash Player installed properly?

Tags: flash

YouTube is working fine, but some other websites show an error about missing Adobe Flash Player. How can I get rid of this and verify that Adobe Flash Player installed properly?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: YouTube can use HTML5 video, so that doesn't actually say anything about flash. How did you install it, and what browser are you using?

Comment: An up-to-date summary of Flash on Ubuntu is available at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Comment: Hi zondo, I am using firefox and vivaldi browser.

Answer (score 1):

For verification you can use Adobe official page:
https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

Or unofficial:
http://flashbuilder.eu/flash-player-version.html

Seems that you don't have Flash player installed. I recommend to do an easy install and install all "restricted" software packages, including FP.
Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using both Firefox and Vivaldi, you should install the [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html#adobe-flashplugin) package from Canonical Partner. It provides Flash for both those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the plug-in overview page of your web browser and look for Flash Player. For Firefox that is `about:plugins`; Chromium and Chrome accept the same but will redirect it to `chrome://plugins`.

Watch out for the possibility that your web browser may be configured to disregard and disable plug-ins globally in which case they may show an empty plug-in listing even though Flash Player was installed successfully.